# КДЕ: обработчик двойного нажатия на alt

Tags: linux, kde

Хочу, чтобы по двойному нажатию на alt, я мог закрыть окно (сэмулировать нажатие alt+f4).
В винде для этого у меня был ahk. Не подскажете, как можно реализовать это здесь?

Я это вижу так: должен стоять какой-то обработчик нажатий, который бы ловил каждой нажатие на alt, затем, он бы запускал скрипт (скрипт я написать смогу, мне скорее нужен именно обработчик), в котором бы был бы описан автомат и в соответствии с которым бы делалось то, что мне нужно.

P.S. двойное нажатие на альт не является комбинацией клавиш, поэтому прошу не предлагать их (комбинации клавиш) в качестве ответа, если только вы не знаете четкого плана, по достижение описанной мной цели с их использованием.

Comment: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/shortcuts.html

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, да, клево. Комбинации клавиш. Проблема только в том, что двойное нажатие альта -- не комбинация клавиш. Даже одинарное нажатие альта -- это не комбинация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил следующим образом:
установил пакет ksuperkey, изначально позволяющий переназначать нажатие клавиши windows, но который так же может переназначить и любой другой модификатор:
`ksuperkey -e 'Alt_L=Control_L|Shift_L|F8'`
И назначил на комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+Shift+F8 выполнение следующего скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e "/tmp/ALT_FLAG" ]
then
    cur_time=$(( $(date +%s%N)/1000000))
    diff=$(( $cur_time - $(cat /tmp/ALT_LAST_PRESS) ))
    if (( diff>300 ))
    then
        echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000)) > /tmp/ALT_LAST_PRESS
        xdotool key Alt
    else
        if (( diff<70 ))
        then
        exit
        else
            xdotool key alt+F4
            rm /tmp/ALT_FLAG;
            rm /tmp/ALT_LAST_PRESS;
        fi
    fi
else
    touch /tmp/ALT_FLAG;
    echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000)) > /tmp/ALT_LAST_PRESS;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Я, через меню, настраиваю так:

- Настройка
- Параметры системы
- Комбинации клавиш
- Дальше - выбирайте сами...

Comment: Как я писал в комментарии выше, я знаю о настройках комбинаций клавиш, и двойное нажатие на альт комбинацией клавиш не является. Здесь нужно что-то, что было бы способно по нажатию на альт запустить скрипт, в котором бы поднимались флаги удержания клавиши и ее отпускания и действий в зависимости от флагов.